# Calcite LogicalAggregate

Tags: apache-calcite

What is a proper way to associate an `AggregateCall` that is part of a `HAVING` expression with a corresponding field in a `RelRecordType` for the `LogicalAggregate`? If the `AggregateCall` is not part of the `SELECT` clause, the `LogicalAggregate`'s `RelRecordType` still has it, but the `AggregateCall`'s `name` attribute is set to `NULL` and `RelRecordType.getField(AggregateCall.getName())` can't be used in this case. If the `AggregateCall` is a part of the final output, its `name` is set and  `RelRecordType.getField(AggregateCall.getName())` returns the right field.

Answer (score 1):

Use field ordinals rather than names.

In the world of Calcite `RelNode`s and `RexNode`s, field names are not that important; they exist mainly to help you understand the purpose of fields when debugging. Names of `AggregateCall`s are even less important; they exist so that `Aggregate` can give reasonable names to its fields, and if they don't exist, that's fine.

If your `SELECT` has *N* fields (numbered 0 .. *N*-1) and a `HAVING` clause, you will likely add the `HAVING` predicate as field N, apply a `Filter` relational operator, then apply a `Project` so that only fields 0 .. *N*-1 are returned. I'm pretty sure that this is what `SqlToRelConverter` does already.